# How to Get around Hard Coding the Host Session ID in vbScript or VBA code

Tags: session, macros, ibm-midrange, host

I have novice knowledge working with PCOMM on the AS400. I have written 15 VBA scripts in Excel which calls AS400 Macros. To get the programs to work the AS400 has to be at the Login Screen and the Active Host Session MUST be set at "D". It is the Host Session that is giving me the blues. As there are many using the same PC, I never know which Host Session the AS400 will active at any point in time... sometimes "A", sometimes "B", or there may be multiple open sessions on the same screen.

The top few lines of my VBA script is below. Is there a way I can define the script to avoid using the Host Session ID ("D" in this case) so my script will work with any ID ("A" or "B", etc)

```
     Sub APVCHDET()
     Set autECLSession = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLSession")
     autECLSession.SetConnectionByName ("D")
```

> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > > >                                         [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xocWv.jpg)

Comment: Please do not insert an image, it is hard to debug code from an image. Instead cut and paste the code from your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I found this in the documentation:

```
Dim SessObj as Object
Dim autECLConnList as Object

Set autECLConnList = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnList")
Set SessObj = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLSession")

' Initialize the session
autECLConnList.Refresh
SessObj.SetConnectionByHandle(autECLConnList(1).Handle)

SessObj.StopCommunication()
```

More [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQ5Y_5.9.0/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/html/host_access08.htm). It's a little like drinking from a fire hose though.

Comment: Thanks.  Sadly it did not solve my problem.  Added the code snipet you provided and the VBA stopped at the line, below marked with 'XXXXX

Dim autECLSession As Object
Dim SessObj As Object
Dim autECLConnList As Object

Set autECLConnList = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnList")
Set SessObj = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLSession")

' 
autECLConnList.Refresh
SessObj.SetConnectionByHandle (autECLConnList(1).Handle)
Set autECLSession = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLSession")
'autECLSession.SetConnectionByName ("D") 'Commented Out
''
'
   autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable 'XXXXX

Comment: I looked at your image. Why do you have `Set SessObj = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLSession")` and `Set autECLSession = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLSession")`? I would only use one of those. And you are only using autECLSession, but SessObj has the expected session object.

Comment: Hi Jmarkmurphy... Thanks to you I have solved my problem... I have made the change you recommended and all 20 of my automation scripts are working perfectly.  I have one last question:  I commented out the "SessObj.StopCommunication()".  Should that code go at the very end of the automation script?  I do not see any adverse impact of not using that line.  Thanks again... Al

Answer (score 0):

`Set SessObj = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLSession")`, in ur code, SessObj used for set which session need to be connected. regarding ur question to Jmarkmurphy, commented out the `"SessObj.StopCommunication()"`, this has the same effect as going to the PCOMM emulator Communication menu and choosing Disconnect.

Finally regarding your original issue, error on `"autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable"`, as mentioned at the very beginning, u have set to connect with session by using `"SessObj"` hence, for `"autECLSession"` has not been used at all to connect with any connection, that's why popup the error "The Session has not been set for this object"